# TinyMCE Weird Display Behaviour in IE8+

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, tinymce

TinyMCE is appearing with far more spacing than it should.

This is a new problem I have run across and I have put TinyMCE in alot of sites, and never had this issue:

[image: Image of Issue]

I have tried changing TinyMCE load to various ones, even copying direct from TinyMCE examples on their website, and it does the same thing. Also removed my CSS form styles without any luck. Its just an issue in IE8/9 but not in Firefox or Chrome.

My header is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!-- GET CSS -->
<link href="http://resources.domain.co.nz/styles/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<link href="http://resources.domain.co.nz/styles/administration.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<link href="http://resources.domain.co.nz/styles/webfont.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<!--Get SCRIPTS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://resources.domain.co.nz/scripts/slimScroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://resources.domain.co.nz/scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,visualchars,nonbreaking",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,sub,sup,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,print",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,insertdate,inserttime,|,search,replace,iespell",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : false,
});
</script>
```

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: put up a link or example jsfiddle , you might get some replies.

Comment: @sabithpocker: totally agree